# Django render json response with html elements

Tags: javascript, html, django

I'm learning ajax. for example I want to fetch some items. As the json only contains dict-like data, I have to render them as complicated html elements.

I'm thinking about where to do the render job. If done in frontend, using javascript to render such complicated html element will be painful.

So I thought it will be better to leverage Django template. And What I need is to render it using html template, and put the whole html elements into a string in json, and return the json. So my frontend will easy fetch the rendered element like data['element'] and append it to my page.

But I don't know how to do this in Django, ususally I render a html page and return it directly. But how can it render the html elements and put it into json?
Or is there better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this just fine.

Lets say at `your/html/url` you have something that returns a rendered django template.

Then in your javascript, all you need to do is

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'your/html/url',
    action: 'get',
    success: function(response) {
        $("#place-you-want-answer").html(response);
    }  
})'
```

That's because all a django endpoint does is return an HTML-string. Usually when your browser hits it, it is loading an entire page, but you can use it in a javascript get-request as well.

If you're just learning, this is a fine way of doing it. But if this is for a long-term project, I would seriously consider using a javascript framework instead. They make turning objects into HTML much easier. React is really nice, for example.